# Error Showing in (int i=n;i&gt;0;i--)

Tags: java

I tried to write code for an factorial number program,following code

```
public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );


        System.out.println("Enter the number whose factorial you want: ");

        int n = in .nextInt();
        int f = 1;
        for (int i = n; i & gt; 0; i--) //error show what's wrong in for loop {
            f = f * i;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of " + n + " is " + f);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have copy pasted code from somewhere. So `&gt;` appare instead of `>`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes your error point is `& gt;` which is not an operator actual operator is `>`. `&gt;` is **XML encoded** from of `>`.

Use this:

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
```

Instead of

```
for (int i = n; i & gt; 0; i--)
```

> This happens usually when you copy past code from somewhere.

---

Complete code should be:

```
public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );


        System.out.println("Enter the number whose factorial you want: ");    
        int n = in .nextInt();
        int f = 1;
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) //error show what's wrong in for loop {
            f = f * i;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of " + n + " is " + f);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Manwal you save me

Comment: Hey @Sanjay hope this helped you. You can accept answer by clicking on button at bottom of vote if this is all you need.